# display:flex is randomly turning into display:block with jquery hide/show and google webfont

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm getting unpredictable results when calling jquery's `css("display")` on an element; sometimes it's `flex`, other times it is `block`. What's strange is that this error is only present when I'm using jquery's `show`/`hide`, and the error happens about 50% of the time. What's even more strange is that I'm seeing these results *before* `hide` even runs.

**Update:** It seems to also be tied to [this google webfont css](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Forum) I'm including. If I remove the font the problem goes away. This is all very strange.

Here's a simplification of my code:

---

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("1 display: " + $("#foo").css("display"));
    $("#foo").hide();
    console.log("2 display: " + $("#foo").css("display"));
    $("#foo").show();
    console.log("3 display: " + $("#foo").css("display"));
});
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/JavaScript"
            src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="script.js"></script>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Forum' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foo" class="centerer">
            <p>Hello!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#foo {
    background: white url("bg.jpg") center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100vw auto;
}

.centerer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

---

The correct behavior should print out:

```
1 display: flex
2 display: none
3 display: flex
```

But what I'm seeing about 50% of the time is:

```
1 display: block
2 display: none
3 display: block
```

Any ideas on **what could be causing this? I want to know why**.

Comment: show() and hide() will always result in "block" / "none". If you want flex instead you should use css classes like this:
`$('#foo').addClass('flex');
$('#foo').removeClass('flex').addClass('hideFlex')`

Comment: `hide()` doesn't know about `flex`.  Wrap your `#foo` in a div with `display:block` and  it should work.

Comment: @FabianLurz @thebjorn the documentation of `hide` claims it will save the previous display value for `show` to restore. Also, note how "`1 display: block`" gets printed *before* `hide` even gets called.

Comment: Works fine in jquery 2.1.3 http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/gohn7cxs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your bad output your initial value of display is **block**. This is not a bug with the show method.

Are you sure than your script is execute after the CSS calculation ?

Check your document structure :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- css include/import -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- html body -->
    <!-- script include/import -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just posted the full html to the question. Maybe I got the order wrong?

Comment: Yes, your script import is before the CSS. The best practice is to put it at the end of the body for optimize the loading and the exécution order.

Comment: Changing the order of the includes seemed to make the problem go away. I'm going to leave this question open though because I haven't found out why this matters here.

Comment: This come from the execution order of the script in the page's construction. In your first version your execute the script before the CSS was load. The document ready is fire when the DOM is ready but before the end of the CSS render. When you get the display value, maybe the render is finish but not sure. It's depend of your computer resources. If you put the script to the end, your load and execute the script after the CSS calculation and all work fine. I think you can also set a timeout to 500 but it's ugly.

Answer (score 1):

For JQuery hide() and show() functions to work properly (maintain original display value) the element should be part of the DOM at the point in time when function is called. Maybe Google Webfonts temporary unloads your content from DOM...

Problem can be reproduced like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/u442nsko/1

```
#foo {
    display: flex;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    var my = $("<div id='foo'>......</div>")
    console.log("1 display: " + my.css("display"));
    my.hide();
    console.log("2 display: " + my.css("display"));
    my.show();
    console.log("3 display: " + my.css("display"));
    $("body").append(my);
    console.log("4 display: " + my.css("display"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: According to http://api.jquery.com/hide/ hide will save the previous state. But as it seems it is not working in your case.
Solution:

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("1 display: " + $("#foo").css("display"));
    $("#foo").addClass('hideFlex');
    console.log("2 display: " + $("#foo").css("display"));
    $("#foo").removeClass('hideFlex');
    console.log("3 display: " + $("#foo").css("display"));
});
```

css:

```
   .hideFlex{
    display:none;
    }
```

So replace the js with my js and add .hideFlex to your css. Should work then.

Comment: "The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block"), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline." from jQuery API documentation

Comment: I like yours better.   Better a hide class than a flex class, yeah?

Comment: @Techniv Same here, so what could his problem be?  I tested it on fiddle down to v1.6 and works fine on there.

Comment: My guess would be, that it is somehow overwritten by the browser (keyword html boilerplate)

Comment: I have a supposition in my answer. But not sure.

Comment: It appears that the element you are showing/hiding must be part of the DOM when you first do it... Otherwise it will overwrite display property. Check this one: https://jsfiddle.net/u442nsko/1/ Firefox and Chrome will give different values for the first log line :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in the most recent version of jquery

**IMO whatever the problem is, lies with your code (maybe even the CSS) setting that display to block at some point and you are not realizing it.**

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/gohn7cxs/)

[image]

Try using addClass and removeClass.  Hide and show set the value to block.

```
.flex {

display: flex;

}

$('selector').addClass('flex');  //show
$('selector').removeClass('flex'); //hide
```